# How to append data in a GoogleSheet using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet with data, but it has one problem daily I have to put data(same type of data), someone knows how to append data in a google sheet using python, help me.

I have that type of result and that is in string

```py
print(time, " ", todayMaxProfit, " ", todayMaxLoss, " ", pl, " ", len(
orderList), " First pair sum:- ", int(orderList[0][4]+orderList[1][4]))

"2021-08-18 15:00:00  [1451, '2021-08-18 11:07:00']  [-10203, '2021-08-18 14:45:00']  -6900  2  First pair sum:-  234"
```

I want to append data at last.

[image]

Comment: what did you try? There is python module for this. And you should find many questions on Stackoveflow with some code. Or you may even find some tutorials on internet.

Comment: Where does your data come from?

Comment: @iansedano I made a python script that collects data from the stoke market and that gives me some results like one line result and I have to add that on the sheet daily that's why I ask that.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the result you get?

Comment: @iansedano `2021-08-18 15:00:00  [1451, '2021-08-18 11:07:00']  [-10203, '2021-08-18 14:45:00']  -6900  2  First pair sum:-  234` that is result of last Wednesday.

Comment: Is that a string? i.e `result = "2021-08-18 15:00:00  [1451, '2021-08-18 11:07:00']  [-10203, '2021-08-18 14:45:00']  -6900  2  First pair sum:-  234"` -- please add this info to your original question.

Comment: @iansedano i post it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236232/discussion-between-brijesh-kalkani-and-iansedano).

Comment: To connect python to sheets, just follow their Google’s example code: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python. Then go here to add a write function: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values

Comment: @DanielRedgate I have already data on the sheet and I want to append more data like line by line

Comment: See my second link. It tells you how to append values to a table (it automatically finds the end for you)

Comment: are you trying to add these values ```"2021-08-18 15:00:00  [1451, '2021-08-18 11:07:00']  [-10203, '2021-08-18 14:45:00']  -6900  2  First pair sum:-  234"``` to the sheet in different cells?

Comment: @LakshanCosta yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How to append values to a Google Spreadsheet with Python.

1. Follow the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) to get set up. Make sure you follow all the steps exactly! You will need to do this for every project you start that uses the API so you might as well follow the instructions here. Make sure you get the expected output before moving on!
2. You can then modify the quickstart to make getting the `service` a separate function:

```py
def getService():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    return build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
```

3. Once you have the service, you can make calls to the Sheets API. For example:

```py
service = getService()
appendValues(service)
            
values = [
    [time, todayMaxProfit, todayMaxLoss, pl, len(orderList), int(orderList[0][4]+orderList[1][4])]
]
    
body = {'values': values}
result = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId="13rdolwpUD4h4RTuEgn1QbtgPMpJiZGMFubdh4loAfNQ", range="Sheet1!A1",
    valueInputOption="RAW", body=body).execute()
```

Note that the format the `values` has to be in is a two dimensional list.:

```
[
    [A1, B1, C1],
    [A2, B2, C2]
]
```

Using the [`append`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) method, will simply add the row, as-is to the end of the sheet. The `append` takes a few arguments:

- spreadsheetId - the `id` of the spreadsheet that you want to append values to
- range - the rough range where the data is found. The Sheets API will try to evaluate the data in the Sheet and guess where the last row is. Usually, if you just have a table filled with data from `A1` to the bottom, you can just leave this as `A1`, or maybe `C5`, if you have headers or spaces. The idea is to point the API to the collection of data that you want to append to.
- valueInputOption - this can usually be left as "RAW" which just inserts the data as it is passsed.
- body, where you have your two dimensional list of data.

#### References

- [Guide to Reading and Writing Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)
- [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)
- [`append`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can try pygsheets, it works good and is easy to use.

```py
import pygsheets
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='creds.json')
sh = gc.open('sheetname')  # Open GoogleSheet
worksheet1 = sh.worksheet('title', 'worksheetname')  # choose worksheet to work with
worksheed1.append_table(values=["Date", "blah", 1, '\'+', "ect"])  # append row to worksheet
```